# How to validate Spring-Boot mapped Entitys

Tags: java, spring, validation, jpa, entity

Iam trying to validate the following Scheme with the Spring Validator:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/bankcode-service")
@Validated
public class BankcodeController {

@Autowired
Delegator delegator;
@Autowired
Delegator delegator;

@Autowired
BankcodeRepository bankcodeRepository;

@DeleteMapping(path = "/bankcode", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ResponseBody
public DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<String>> lock(@Valid HttpEntity<BankcodeJSONEntity> httpEntity) {

    DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<String>> response = new DeferredResult<>();
    if (httpEntity.getBody() == null) {
        response.setResult(new ResponseEntity<>("The request was empty!", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST));
        return response;
    }
    response.setResult(delegator.delegateUseCase(new LockBankcodeProd(bankcodeRepository, httpEntity.getBody())));
    return response;
}
```

The DTO used looks like that:

```
@Data
public class BankcodeJSONEntity {

@NotNull
@Size(min = 8, max = 8)
private String bankcode;
@NotNull
@Size(min = 11, max = 11)
private String bic;
@NotNull
private String ticket;

@Basic
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@NotNull
private Date date;
@NotNull
private String category;
@NotNull
private String name;

}
```

But no matter if I pass in:

```
{"bankcode":"00000000", "bic":"AAAAAAAAAAA", "ticket":"SPOC-000000", "date":"2020-01-17", "category":"Fusion", "name":"Fantasiebank"}
```

Or an invalid one:

```
{"bankcode":"21750000", "bic":"AAAAAAAA", "ticket":"SPOC-000000", "date":"2020-01-17", "category":"Fusion", "name":"Fantasiebank"}
```

There is no constraintvalidationexception thrown. In many Tutorials I've seen that the validation is mostly done with concrete Arguments instead of a DTO. Is the DTO Validation possible because I can only have 7 Constructor Arguments before SonarLint lowers my Code Quality.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: what happens if you remove `HttpEntity ` from parameter . and keep parameter as `@Valid BankcodeJSONEntity entity`. Because HttpEntity represents HTTP request or response  including headers and body, usually used with RestTemplate.

Comment: And for controller, usually as response wrapper.

Comment: Could you post this as an Answer so I can accept it? Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remove HttpEntity from parameter. Change your parameter as `@Valid BankcodeJSONEntity entity`. 
Because HttpEntity represents HTTP request or response including headers and body, usually used with RestTemplate. And for controller, usually as response wrapper.

```
public DeferredResult<ResponseEntity<String>> lock(@Valid BankcodeJSONEntityentity) {
```

Comment: I had to use lock(@Valid @RequestBody BankcodeJSONEntityentity) to make it work. Thank you for your Help!